# Show that there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in A$ for all $n \geq N$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Question:**
>
> Let $A$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$.
>
> Suppose than $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^p$ such that $x_n \to x$, where $x \in A$.
>
> Show that there is a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in A$ for all $n \geq N$.

If my understanding is correct, we have to prove that every term of the sequence $(x_n)$ will lie within some open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ after some $N^{th}$ term.

Is this correct? If so, how can I go about proving this?

Comment: No, you actually need to use that fact in order to show that after this $N$-th term every term of the sequence will lie within $A$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke - that is exactly what i meant :). Because if it lies within $B(x, \epsilon)$ then it is an interior point of $A$. Hence it also lies in $A$ since $A$ is open.

Comment: Do you know why there is an $N$ such that $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$ ?

Comment: @StefanHamcke Yes :). From the definition of a limit of sequences. $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x \iff \forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - x | < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N_\epsilon$. Now we are given that $x_n \to x$ hence we know there must be some $N$ so that the above mentioned definition holds.

Comment: @Exactly. But you want to show that there is some $N$ such that all $x_n$ for $n>N$ are in $A$. So if you know that there's some $B(x,\epsilon)$ within $A$, then you are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some books this is an alternative definition of convergence: instead of open balls we say $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ if for every open $A\ni x$, there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $(x_n)\subset A$ for every $n\geq N$.

I'll prove that this is equivalent to the old definition. First, the easy direction (by taking the new definition): since every open ball $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is, well... open, so our definition means that there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that etc.

The converse, which is what you want to prove, is proved by noting that, since $A$ is open there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $B(x,\varepsilon)\subset A$. Remember that our hypothesis is now the "old definition", so there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $$(x_n)\subset B(x,\varepsilon) \subset\,...$$
Fill in the last inclusion and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct.

Let me explain you how this works.

SinceA is an open set and x $\in$ A, therefore exists an $\epsilon$ such that the the ball B(x,$\epsilon$)$\subset$ A. Therefore by the definition of convergence for that $\epsilon$ exists a N $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n}$ $\in$ A.